# CakePHP and reusable approach

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I would develop my CakePHP application in the most reusable way. I'd like to treat it as webservices, so I don't want to strictly bind controller with view. My idea is: controller just returns json info, the view calls the controller and get the json and make html output.

How can I realize that? Could be a good approch, developing pages rather than views, and inside that pages call the webservices previously developed.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a reasonable idea, because all your views would have to parse JSON, this doesn't make it more reusable in itself.

Comment: I didn't intend to offend you, sorry if it sounded like this. It pretty much depends on what kind of project you are developing. If you want something with a lot of content that should be indexed by Google (e.g. a classic CMS, blog, etc.), than it would definitely be the wrong approach. If you build some highly interactive app that relies on ajax anyway, you could ignore clients with JS turned off, for sure.

Comment: No, no it's ok with your comment, don't worry ;) 
You are right, I can use this approach 'cause this project is an intranet site, used by employee to manage their job tasks, so there are no problem about indexing. In few mounths I will understand if this approach was cleare and reusable.

Comment: Under the circumstances you describe, this sounds a lot more sensible than I was thinking in the first place. Still I question myself, how this should improve reusability since you are only moving the view-specific parts of the application from the Views to the JS. Please let us know about your experience, when you finished this! :-)

Comment: My reasoning is: My controller just return json code. View is almost nonexistent, all presentation layer is demanded to Pages. Each page call, a proper controller, then javascript will process json, creating  HTML output. The code (should be) reusable, controller is really simple to read, all the chaos of the presentation layer is *really* outside model or controller. 
In the next months if I need an alternative version this can be easily created using an API-like approach. But this is just a prediction, and reality could be a real chaos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even forget about creating view files, using $this->set('_serialize', array('people')); in your PeopleController::show()

Answer (score 0):

Well Cake is kinda' works like this "out of the box". You can use `Router::parseExtensions();` to define what type of data you would like to serve. For example in `app/Config/routes.php`:

```
Router::parseExtensions('xml','json');
```

This will make it possible to detect what kind of request is incoming. For example if someone requests:
`www.example.com/people/list.json` or `www.example.com/people/list.xml`, in your PeopleController's list() method you'd be able to detect what kind of resource is being requested - json or xml, or of course any other 
extension you define. This is what the [RequestHandlerComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html) is used for. You can check if it is xml for example:

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isXml()) {
//Some code
}
```

The different extensions are only different representation of the data, so it shouldn't matter what exactly you're serving. From v2.1 Cake will automatically switch the view class when it sees a JSON or XML request, which takes us to the new [JSON and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

All you will have to do is provide the views in the appropriate places.
In `View/People` (as for this example) you would have:

```
..View/People/
      list.ctp
      xml/
         list.ctp - XML view
      json/
         list.ctp - JSON view
```